# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (Metis Theme Template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new using jQuery and I'd like to get a little bit of help with this.

I'm trying to test a theme template and the following jQuery code is trouble me (this code is for default):

```
    <!--jQuery -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.list-inline li > a').click(function() {
            var activeForm = $(this).attr('href') + ' > form';
            //console.log(activeForm);
            $(activeForm).addClass('animated fadeIn');
            //set timer to 1 seconds, after that, unload the animate animation
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(activeForm).removeClass('animated fadeIn');
            }, 1000);
          });
        });
      })(jQuery);
```

and I'm always getting the same error:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
})(jQuery);
```

Do you have any idea? This code is from a theme template (Metis Bootstrap Admin Template).

Comment: Do you still have the error or is it solved with the CDN url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CDN` url of `jQuery` library is not working.

Use:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
//           ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it from local, specify the protocol:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wasn't it `http` before!